# Using react testing library and easy-peasy state management

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, easy-peasy

I am using easy `peasy` and `RTL` for testing and am getting error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
```

when running the test. The app works otherwise in the browser.

Anyone know of any solutions?

I was doing a test with RTL but can never seem to get past the type error.

Comment: Hello, please provide some code so we can reproduce your issue or, even better, provide a CodeSandbox with your issue.  (codesandbox.io)